# Modifying req.path in expressjs middleware

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to make a middleware to remove locale strings from the path (e.g. `/de/about` -> `/about`), and I'm using express. I tried the following middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var localeMatch = /^\/([a-z]{2}(?:\-[A-Z]{2})?)(\/.+)$/.exec(req.path);

    if (localeMatch) {
        req.locale = localeMatch[1];
        req.path = localeMatch[2];
    } else {
        req.locale = 'en-GB';
    }

    next();
});
```

It didn't work because `req.path` is read only. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Express' [mount paths](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.mountpath). You can have a handling function on each "sub app", yet have all your locales go to the same route.